# Converting a binary file to a readable text file in C Linux

Tags: c, file, binary

I was given a binary file that I need to convert to a readable text file using C and Linux. The code below was partially taken from this site.

I have tried several algorithms I have found but none seem to work.

```
unsigned char buffer[1000];
FILE *input;
FILE *output;
int n = 0;
int count = 0;

input = fopen("memdb","rb");
output = fopen("output.out","wb");

while(!feof(input))
{
    n = fread(buffer,1,1000,input);

    count += n;

    fwrite(buffer,1,n,output);
}

fclose(input);
fclose(output);
```

Comment: Something I forgot to mention.  The code will compile and produce the output.out file.  However it will be called a shared library file and will not be viewable.  I'm a little new to Linux so I'm not sure exactly what to do.

Comment: "I have tried several algorithms" --> post the code of one of those algorithms you tried to increase the veracity of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code performs an exact copy of the binary contents of **memdb** to **output.out**. No conversion to readable text at all.  Note that `while(!feof(input))` is not a correct way to test for end of file, but in your particular case it does not pose a problem.

Your goal is unclear:

- what do you mean by *readable text file*?
- what kind of data does **memdb** contain?
- do you want to convert non ASCII data to some alternate form that is more *readable* by a human being?

Here is an alternative that produces a hex dump:

```
/* copy binary file memdb as hex, returns the number of bytes or negative for error */
int copy_memdb(void) {
    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;
    int c, count;

    input = fopen("memdb", "rb");
    if (input == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    output = fopen("output.out", "w");
    if (output == NULL) {
        fclose(input);
        return -2;
    }
    count = 0;
    while ((c = getc(input)) != EOF) {
        if (count++ % 16 == 0) {
            putc('\n', output);
        } else {
            putc(' ', output);
        }
        fprintf(%02X", c);
    }
    if (count > 0)
        putc('\n', output);

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return count;
}
```